# AngularJS - Nothing is defined while testing

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework, karma-jasmine

I'm trying to test my AngularJS app (using ionic) with Karma and Jasmine but really everything is `undefined` when starting the `karma.conf.js` file.

I've searched on Google for answers and tried to change the order of my files in `karma.conf.js`, I added `angular-mocks` but nothing seems to be working.

[image: console errors]

### Karma.conf.js

```
    // base path that will be used to resolve all patterns (eg. files, exclude)
basePath: '',


// frameworks to use
// available frameworks: https://npmjs.org/browse/keyword/karma-adapter
frameworks: ['jasmine'],


// list of files / patterns to load in the browser
files: [
  'www/lib/angular/angular.js',
  'www/lib/jquery/dist/jquery.js',
  'www/lib/angular-mocks/angular-mocks.js',
  'www/**/*.js',
  'test/**/*.js'
],
```

Comment: I don't see the `require` library added to karma config

Comment: @maurycy It's not only `require`, it's also `define is not defined`. I don't even use `require' in my project. It must be from the libraries

Comment: AFAIK Karma is using `require`, are you sure the paths are correct?

Comment: @maurycy Yes, paths are correct

Comment: I don't know how to help you, this screenshot is not enough to debug it, you are clearly missing `require`, probably didn't installed all karma required npm modules

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the line `'www/**/*.js',` in the `files` section is what's hurting you. With this pattern you load *every* JS file in your `www` folder, which I can assume is not what you want.

I suggest you be more specific with the files you load. Maybe just the files in `www/js/` folder, for example.